# Database update needs FROM clause, but FROM clause causes error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been trying to figure out how to update the ID of the newest person in my database for 36 hours. It moans about the `clients` in the `FROM` clause, but when I remove that clause, the update affects every ID in the whole database.

```
UPDATE clients SET ID = $id WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM clients)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So now we need to guess which exact error you got?

Comment: Please provide table structure and error

Comment: Is `id` a Primary Key? If yes - then it is a really bad practice, don't change PK ever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace it with

```
UPDATE clients SET ID = $id ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 1
```

**PS**: this query solves the original task specified in the question "to update the id of the newest person in my database"

Comment: Thanks mate, was convinced my way was correct, but no you are correct :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't update a table using a `WHERE` condition aggregated from the exact same table.

perhaps you want this:

```
UPDATE
    client
SET
    client.[id] = $id
ORDER BY
    client.[timestamp] DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: There is, but that would be a nested query, aka a derived table, not the *exact same table* which is what I said

Comment: in this particular case we also have a *nested query*. Double nesting is not about "derived table" but about a mysql query analyzer that is not good enough to detect such cheats